# How to store font size in local storage

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a simple resizing font size for the user but having issue storing it in the local storage so that next time the user refreshes the page or revisit it'll set to be the desired font size. For the moment i only get a page to work when im on it once i leave it is all being reset.
https://jsfiddle.net/v77z0pzd/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var size = localStorage.getItem('size');

//min font size
var min=9;  

//max font size
var max=16; 

//grab the default font size
var reset = $('p').css('fontSize'); 

//font resize these elements
var elm = $('p.intro, p.ending');  

//set the default font size and remove px from the value
var size = str_replace(reset, 'px', ''); 

//Increase font size
$('a.fontSizePlus').click(function() {

    //if the font size is lower or equal than the max value
    if (size<=max) {

        //increase the size
        size++;

        //set the font size
        elm.css({'fontSize' : size});
        localStorage.setItem('size', size);
    }

    //cancel a click event
    return false;   

});

$('a.fontSizeMinus').click(function() {

    //if the font size is greater or equal than min value
    if (size>=min) {

        //decrease the size
        size--;

        //set the font size
        elm.css({'fontSize' : size});
    }

    //cancel a click event
    return false;   

});

//Reset the font size
$('a.fontReset').click(function () {

    //set the default font size 
     elm.css({'fontSize' : reset});     
});});
```

Where should i place localStorage.

Comment: In every event handler where you modify font size.

Comment: Note you are overwriting the size you get from `localStorage` by having this: `var size = str_replace(reset, 'px', '');` If you want to store the default size choose a different variable name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fiddle doesn't work even when a `localStorage` key of `size` is set is simply because you are not setting the stored size on reload—in fact, you are overwriting it with this line:

```
var size = str_replace(reset, 'px', '');
```

Your strategy should be as follow—I have reused your code, but rearranged it a little bit:

1. Detect the default font size
2. Define elements whose font size can be changed
3. Get `size` from localStorage, if exists:

   - If it does, set the elements to stored font size
   - If not, fall back to default size

By checking if `size` is truthy, then you can use it to set the font-size when the page is reloaded:

```
// Grab the default font size
var reset = $('p').css('fontSize');

// Font resize these elements
var elm = $('p.intro, p.ending');

// Retrieve stored size from localStorage
var size = localStorage.getItem('size');
if (size) {
  // Yes, we found it
  elm.css('font-size', size + 'px');
} else {
  // No, it's not defined/stored
  // Set the default font size and remove px from the value
  size = str_replace(reset, 'px', '');
}
```

See working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/v77z0pzd/6/

Answer (score 0):

Relevant differences

`var size = localStorage.getItem('size');` becomes

`var size = localStorage.getItem('size') || $('p').css('fontSize');`

Set `elm.css({'fontSize': size});` after `var elm = $('p.intro, p.ending');`

Remove `var size = str_replace(reset, 'px', '');`

Add missing `localStorage.setItem('size', size);` when reducing font size.

Complete file

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/SIrNqv8h6QGKDuNoLGA4iret+kyesCkHGzVUUV0shc="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
      body {
        font-size:12px;
        font-family:arial;
      }

      a {
        color:#c00;
        text-decoration:none;
      }

      a:hover {
        color:#f00;
        text-decoration:underline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
    <body>

    <a href="#" class="fontSizePlus">A+</a> |
    <a href="#" class="fontReset">Reset</a> |
    <a href="#" class="fontSizeMinus">A-</a>

    <p class="intro">Donec viverra auctor lobortis. Pellentesque eu est a nulla placerat dignissim. Morbi a enim in magna semper bibendum. Etiam scelerisque, nunc ac egestas consequat, odio nibh euismod nulla, eget auctor orci nibh vel nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris vel neque sit amet nunc gravida congue sed sit amet purus. Quisque lacus quam, egestas ac tincidunt a, lacinia vel velit. Aenean facilisis nulla vitae urna tincidunt congue sed ut dui. Morbi malesuada nulla nec purus convallis consequat. Vivamus id mollis quam.</p> 

    <p>Morbi ac commodo nulla. In condimentum orci id nisl volutpat bibendum. Quisque commodo hendrerit lorem quis egestas. Maecenas quis tortor arcu. Vivamus rutrum nunc non neque consectetur quis placerat neque lobortis. Nam vestibulum, arcu sodales feugiat consectetur, nisl orci bibendum elit, eu euismod magna sapien ut nibh. Donec semper quam scelerisque tortor dictum gravida. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam pulvinar, odio sed rhoncus suscipit, sem diam ultrices mauris, eu consequat purus metus eu velit.</p>

    <p>Proin metus odio, aliquam eget molestie nec, gravida ut sapien. Phasellus quis est sed turpis sollicitudin venenatis sed eu odio. Praesent eget neque eu eros interdum malesuada non vel leo. Sed fringilla porta ligula egestas tincidunt. Nullam risus magna, ornare vitae varius eget, scelerisque a libero. Morbi eu porttitor ipsum. Nullam lorem nisi, posuere quis volutpat eget, luctus nec massa. Pellentesque aliquam lacinia tellus sit amet bibendum. Ut posuere justo in enim pretium scelerisque. Etiam ornare vehicula euismod. Vestibulum at risus augue. Sed non semper dolor. Sed fringilla consequat velit a porta. Pellentesque sed lectus pharetra ipsum ultricies commodo non sit amet velit. Suspendisse volutpat lobortis ipsum, in scelerisque nisi iaculis a. Duis pulvinar lacinia commodo. Integer in lorem id nibh luctus aliquam. Sed elementum, est ac sagittis porttitor, neque metus ultricies ante, in accumsan massa nisl non metus. Vivamus sagittis quam a lacus dictum tempor. Nullam in semper ipsum.</p>

    <p class="ending">Cras a est id massa malesuada tincidunt. Etiam a urna tellus. Ut rutrum vehicula dui, eu cursus magna tincidunt pretium. Donec malesuada accumsan quam, et commodo orci viverra et. Integer tincidunt sagittis lectus. Mauris ac ligula quis orci auctor tincidunt. Suspendisse odio justo, varius id posuere sit amet, iaculis sit amet orci. Suspendisse potenti. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed posuere dignissim odio, nec cursus odio mollis et. Praesent cursus, orci ut dictum.</p>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

      var size = localStorage.getItem('size') || $('p').css('fontSize');

            //min font size
            var min = 9;

            //max font size
            var max = 16;

            //grab the default font size
            var reset = $('p').css('fontSize');

            //font resize these elements
            var elm = $('p.intro, p.ending');
      elm.css({'fontSize': size});

            //Increase font size
            $('a.fontSizePlus').click(function() {

                    //if the font size is lower or equal than the max value
                    if (size<=max) {

                            //increase the size
                            size++;

                            //set the font size
                            elm.css({'fontSize' : size});
                            localStorage.setItem('size', size);
                    }

                    //cancel a click event
                    return false;

            });

            $('a.fontSizeMinus').click(function() {

                    //if the font size is greater or equal than min value
                    if (size>=min) {

                            //decrease the size
                            size--;

                            //set the font size
                            elm.css({'fontSize' : size});
                            localStorage.setItem('size', size);
                    }

                    //cancel a click event
                    return false;

            });

            //Reset the font size
            $('a.fontReset').click(function () {

                    //set the default font size
                    elm.css({'fontSize' : reset});
            });


    });

    //A string replace function
    function str_replace(haystack, needle, replacement) {
            var temp = haystack.split(needle);
            return temp.join(replacement);
    }
    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```